# What is the "Ode to the woman" of Shlomo HaMelech?

Tags: women, song-poetry, tehilim-psalms, king-solomon

I have read things about the "Ode to the woman", written by Shlomo HaMelech but I do not know what it refers to. Is it one of the psalms? Where can I find this "Ode"?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aishes-chayil

Answer (score 9):

It is verses 10 - 31 of [chapter 31 of Proverbs](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2831.htm) (Mishlei), commonly known as Eishes Chayil, or the woman of valor.  It is customarily sung by men on Friday night before Kiddush. The topic of the song is the woman, but it may be an allegory, perhaps for Shabbos, perhaps for something else.

Comment: Seems in places to be an allegory for Torah, like in B.Metz 84b http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=bava_metzia&daf=84b